# PHP - preg_replace with multiple matches

Tags: php, preg-replace

Let's say I have a string like:

```
$text = "<object>item_id1a2b3</object>xxx<object>item_id4c5d6</object>"
```

I want to convert it to:
    %ITEM:1a2b3xxx%ITEM:4c5d6

Here's what I've got:

```
$text = preg_replace("/<object.*item_id([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*<\/object/","%ITEM:$1",$text);
```

This isn't quite right, as the search is greedy.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$text = preg_replace("/<object>.*?item_id([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*?<\/object/","%ITEM:$1",$text);
```

NOTE: Untested

What I did was change the .* to .*?, and to close off your object tag (I thought that might have been a mistake; sorry if that's not correct).  The ? after the .* should make it lazy.

Answer (score 2):

We can make the search non-greedy by using *? in place of *. So final regex becomes:

```
$text = preg_replace("/<object.*?item_id([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*?<\/object>/","%ITEM:$1",$text);
```

I have also added '>' at the end of the regex so as to avoid it from coming in the replaced text.

Answer (score 1):

So why not do smth like this:

```
$text = preg_replace("@<object>item_id([a-zA-Z0-9]+)</object>@", "%ITEM:$1", $text);
```

Or like this:

```
$text = preg_replace("@<object>item_id@", "%ITEM:", $text);
$text = preg_replace("@</object>@", "", $text);
```

NOTE: tested =)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$2` for the next parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to split the string on every instance of ""?

```
$result = '';
$items = explode('<object>', $text);
foreach ($items as $item){
  $result .= '%'.str_replace('</object>', '', $item);
}
echo $result;
```